# HTTP Get request fails when run from Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

I have written a standalone Java program that makes an HTTP GET request call to a particular website using Apache's proxy API. The GET method returns successfully, the response code is 200 and I can see the result. However, when the same code is ran from the same machine inside a Tomcat server, `client.executeMethod(...)` gets stuck.

I've checked the following:

1. The Java program and Tomcat service runs using the same domain administrator account.
2. The code in the standalone Java program and what is executed from Tomcat is exactly the same including Apache versions. So I am baffled why the same code fails to execute from inside Tomcat. Are their any special settings required to configure proxy for Tomcat?

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HostConfiguration;
   import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
   import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
   public class ConnectvIDM {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException {
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();        
           GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://accesspolicy.hwslabs.com/SAAS/API/1.0/GET/metadata/idp.xml");
           HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
           config.setProxy("proxy.some.com", 3128);
           client.setHostConfiguration(config);
           System.out.println("Just before call");
           int returncode = client.executeMethod(method);
           System.out.println("Printing the return code "+returncode);  
       }
   }
   ```

Below is the stack trace when run directly on the Tomcat server:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at com.vmware.vdi.common.saml.SamlHttpUtil.getInputStreamForUrl(SamlHttpUtil.java:47)
at com.vmware.vdi.common.saml.NonCachingHttpMetadataProvider.doGetMetadata(NonCachingHttpMetadataProvider.java:38)
```

Comment: When this code is executed from Tomcat server, the call gets stuck at client.executeMthod, I can never see the next line getting printed, and the tomcat application hangs. Interestingly, the same code executes successfully from the same machine when executed as standalone Java program.

Comment: Any guidance on pointers on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any exception stack trace?

Comment: yes here is the st when run from tomcat server --

Comment: Update the quest with the st when run from the tomcat server, we can see that it fails when we call  executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)

Comment: You seem to have a proxy configured for `proxy.some.com`. Is that proxy host/port reachable from your Tomcat server?

Comment: That proxy/port is reachable from the machine in which the tomcat server is installed. Also standalone program runs successfully on the same machine using the same proxy/port. How can I specially check if that proxy/port is reachable from the Tomcat server? I am assuming if the proxy/port is reachable from the machine in which Tomcat server is installed, then it should be reachable from the tomcat server as well. Please let me know if this understanding is wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run this code from inside tomcat?  IF that is th case, then why is there a main()?  How are you calling it from inside Tomcat?

Comment: This is the code which I executed standalone from the same machine where Tomcat is installed. Already mentioned that in the question. I ran 'almost' the same code from Tomcat server, which fails. I am saying 'almost' because same API call is made to the same proxy/port without the main method and the call gets stuck at client.executeMethod(method);

Comment: Would appreciate if anyone can give any clues as to how to debug this